# Select list not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load data dynamically into my select but I seem to be doing something wrong because it is not working.

This is the html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in travelCompanies" ng-init="getTravelCompanies()">
</select>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$scope.getTravelCompanies = function() {

TCService.get()
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.travelCompanies = data.travelCompanies;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });

};
```

This is the JSON that is being returned from the server:

```
{"travelCompanies":[{"id":1,"name":"AB Travel & Tours","phone_1":"00000001","phone_2":"00000002","address"
:"NONE","email":"ab@gmail.com","website_url":null,"logo_url":null,"is_active":1}]}
```

There are no errors or warnings in my console so I must be doing something wrong I just can't see it.

Comment: what is the ouput from '$scope.travelCompanies' in success?It is the same as above JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `ng-modle` property in  your `select` control.

try this below code instead of your code.

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedTravle" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in travelCompanies" ng-init="getTravelCompanies()">
    </select>
```

Comment: Wow, this i did not know, i honestly thought it didn't matter, i tried it and it works now, thank you. :D

Answer (score 1):

If the **JSON** returned by **success** as above then try this one.

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in travelCompanies.travelCompanies"  ng-model="selectedVal">

    </select>
```

**your model attribute is missing.**